# Failed with the get_object_or_404 django

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is the code:

```
>>> from shortener.models import KirrURL
>>> from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
>>> obj = get_object_or_404(KirrURL,shortcode='pric3e')

Traceback (most recent call last):File"/Users/phil/Desktop/django110/lib/python3.5/site
packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 85, in get_object_or_404
return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/phil/Desktop/django110/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 385, in get
self.model._meta.object_name
shortener.models.DoesNotExist: KirrURL matching query does not exist.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/phil/Desktop/django110/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 93, in get_object_or_404
raise Http404('No %s matches the given query.' %     queryset.model._meta.object_name)
django.http.response.Http404: No KirrURL matches the given query.

>>> obj = KirrURL.objects.get(shortcode='pric3e')
>>> obj
<KirrURL: http://google.com>
>>> obj.id
1
>>> obj.url
'http://google.com'
```

I am practicing django model right now.The problem is when I used the get_object_or_404 trying to get the data which match the second key word argument it somehow failed.When I used get() method.It successes.I think I think I should get the same result here.

```
#Model Class
class KirrURLManager(models.Manager):
    def all(self,*args,**kwargs):
        qs = super(KirrURLManager,self).all(*args,**kwargs)
        qs_main = qs.filter(active=False)
        return qs_main

    def refresh_shortcodes(self,items=None):
        qs = KirrURL.objects.filter(id__gte=1)
        if items is not None and isinstance(items,int):
            qs = qs.order_by('-id')[:items]
        for q in qs:
            q.shortcode = create_shortcode(q)
            q.save()
            print(q.id)
class KirrURL(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=220,)
    shortcode = models.CharField(max_length=SHORTCODE_MAX,unique=True,blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    objects = KirrURLManager()
    some_random = KirrURLManager()
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.shortcode is None or self.shortcode == "":
            self.shortcode = create_shortcode(self)
        super(KirrURL, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.url)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.url)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your custom manager is producing inconsistent results because `.all()` is not always called. If you want this manager to always filter out specific instances, you should override `get_queryset()`. Be sure to include a default manager above your custom manager so you still have a way to access all instances in e.g. the admin.

```
class KirrURLManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(active=False)

class KirrURL(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager() # default manager, put this one first
    custom = KirrURLManager()
```

Now `KurrURL.objects.all()` will return all instances (and `get_object_or_404(KirrURL, shortcode='pric3e')` will be able to find your instance), but you can access all inactive instances using `KirrURL.custom.all()`.

Comment: Yeah!Thanks it helps.And I finally found the problem that the save method I overrides filter wrong value(active should be True this way).Still thanks for the advice.Didn't know that get_objects_or_404 will call the all method before.

Answer (score 6):

I suppose the problem is in overriding `all()` method.
When you are using `get_object_or_404()` it is [calling](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/shortcuts.py#L83) `_get_queryset()` function which returns `manager.all()`. But because of overriding `all()` returns only not active objects and the result of `get_object_or_404(KirrURL,shortcode='pric3e')` is empty.

Comment: Yeah thanks!I found the problem its because I set the wrong value in my save method.